# How to create a cameraOverlayView

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I am really struggling to get my head around how to do this. I have a `UIImagePickerController` which works fine but I want to create my own `CameraOverlayView` so that I can customise the buttons. I can't seem to figure out how to create the overlay in the first place. I have tried so many tutorials and have arrived at the following but it is way off. Can anyone point me to an simple to follow instructions?

- I have created a `UIImagePickerController` that works with standard controls
- For the overlay I have created a new `UIViewController` on my storyboard and linked it to a new class called `ObViewControllerCameraOverlay`
- In the `startCameraControllerFromViewController` method I use the following to hide the standard controls

  cameraUI.showsCameraControls=NO;
- and then this to show the cameraOverlay (which does not compile)

  obViewControllerCameraOverlay *overlay = [[obViewControllerCameraOverlay alloc];
  cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

I know I am doing this wrong but I am stumped as to how to this to work. I have looked at Apple's PhotoPicker too but I just don't get it.

UPDATE:

Where I am now - can anyone tell me  if this is the correct process (I realise frame size needs to be sorted and custom buttons need to be added somehow):

.m file where the 'Take Photo' `UIButton` is located.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *overlay;

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
[self startCameraControllerFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self];
}


- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate
{
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil)) return NO;
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
cameraUI.showsCameraControls=NO;
overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
[controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you just link this overlay view or have you actually instantiated it? Check for null before showing image picker.

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure what you mean. The overlay is a UIViewController (is that correct) which I have subclassed to ObViewControllerCameraOverlay. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your `overlay` is only allocated - not initialized. It should be initialized and it should have it's frame properly set.

Also: `overlayView` should be of a `UIView *` type. If you want to pass an `UIViewController` as an overlay view you have to pass only it's `view` property.

For example:

```
obViewControllerCameraOverlay *overlay = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"obViewControllerCameraOverlay"];

cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = overlay.view;
```

You should change the code of course according to your project and configuration.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. You say I should not use a UIViewController as the overlay but a UIView. Does this mean that I should not add anything to the storyboard but create it all within the one .m file? I have edited my question to reflect latest code.

Comment: You can create this view either programatically or in storyboard. This makes no difference. The main condition is: view has to be instantiated (instance of it has to be initialized) and it's frame has to be set. You can strart with programatically creadted simple view with button added and when that works you can start working on a more complex view from storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty late to this, but here's my code I used to create a UIImagePickerController and a CameraOverlayView. If you want the camera to appear as soon as the view controller opens, make sure you initialize the UIImagePickerController in viewDidAppear like I did (viewDidLoad does not work).

```
@interface CameraViewController ()
@property UIImagePickerController *PickerController;
@property CGFloat HeightOfButtons;
@end


- (UIView *)createCustomOverlayView
{

    // Main overlay view created
    UIView *main_overlay_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    // Clear view (live camera feed) created and added to main overlay view
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UIView *clear_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - self.HeightOfButtons)];
    clear_view.opaque = NO;
    clear_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [main_overlay_view addSubview:clear_view];
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // Creates two red buttons on the bottom of the view (on top of the live camera feed)
    // Then adds the buttons to the main overlay view
    // You can, of course, customize these buttons however you want
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        self.HeightOfButtons = 100;
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        // when a button is touched, UIImagePickerController snaps a picture
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(testIfButtonResponds) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake( i * self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height - self.HeightOfButtons, self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.HeightOfButtons);
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [main_overlay_view addSubview:button];
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return main_overlay_view;
}

- (void)makeCustomCameraAppear
{
    self.PickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.PickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.PickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.PickerController.delegate = self;

    UIView *overlay_view = [self createCustomOverlayView];
    [self.PickerController setCameraOverlayView:overlay_view];

    [self presentViewController:self.PickerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self makeCustomCameraAppear];
}
```